# Redirect InputStream to Socket´s OutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

Suppose I have following Java code on a server:

```
Socket aSocket = new Socket(aInetaddr, aPort); //aSocket is a client i m connecting to
InputStream input = aSocket.getInputStream();
Socket bSocket = new Socket(bInetaddr, bPort); //bSocket is a client i m connectin to
```

Now what I would like to achieve is, to pass the `InputStream` "input" from the `aSocket` to the `bSocket`. I have no information about whats coming from the `InputStream`, or how it is used in the end.

The whole transfer of data has to pass my server, I can't make a direct connection between the 2 clients.

Answer (score 3):

Get the output stream for the second socket and then you can do this trivially using [Apache Commons IOUtils.copy()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29). Amongst many variants there's one that takes an input and output stream as arguments.

Comment: Thx alot, seems exactly like what i m looking for. Do i have to call something like flush(), or does the call of copy() do the whole work? Will this block my code till the whole InputStream is transfered?

Comment: It will block until the stream copied is closed.  You can start another thread or add a task to a thread pool to avoid blocking your current thread.